# Meaning of "inner skater bros"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english

I am confused about the meaning of the phrase "inner skater bro" in the following sentence:

> They are expressing their "inner skater bros" through this excellent
>   game.

The text is a description of a new game. The game involves fishing in a digital farmland. The players earn points by catching animals and birds.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what skater bros have to do with a game about fishing, but the idiom implies that we all have the inclinations of a 90's skateboarding coolkid buried deep in our hearts, waiting to be channeled through this game. This is a universal assumption taken for granted in similar phrases like "inner artist," "inner child," or "inner hippie." I sound like I'm joking but I'm not.